# deploy Node.js +python in Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

I plan to develop a Node.js site and it will call python functions. I am not sure whether this can be deployed in Heroku.

I once have a pure node.js application and it works well in Heroku, could anyone advise if the hybrid can work in Heroku?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app)?

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, I will try later.

Comment: I have already created in [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/66678) but still waiting for approval, though you can visit it.